# React Router and TypeScript Implementation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, tslint

**What is the proper way to wire typescript and react-router together when using `render prop` and a lambda function to pass state and props to child components?**

I'm on a super rocky road trying to wire React Router to TypeScript.

I need to pass props and state from my parent component to its children
rendered by React Router. To do so I'm using the `render prop` as explained [here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/)

To fix:

- `Lambdas are forbidden in JSX attributes due to their rendering performance impact`

I wrote a separate method to fix the Lambda error and passed it to `render` in `Route` i.e:

```
public gameRoute = (props: any, state: object) => {
    return <Game {...props} {...this.state} />
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    const { person, loading, error } = this.state
      return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <div className="App">
            <ul>
              <li>
                <Link to="/">home</Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link to="/play-game">Play Game!</Link>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/play-game" render={this.gameRoute} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      )
  }
```

The main problem is that TypeScript errors:

[image]

- Trying to work around TypeScript and React Router errors, I added the following types to my child component:

```js
// Child Component

import React from 'react'
import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom'

interface GameProps extends RouteComponentProps<any>, React.Props<any> {
  person: object[] | any
  loading: boolean | string
  error: null
}

export const Game: React.SFC<GameProps> = ({ person }) => (
  <p className="error">Game is ON! {person}</p>
)
```

- Then I wrote types to my parent component i.e:

```
// Parent Compoment 

import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { StaticContext } from 'react-router'
import { BrowserRouter, Link, Route, RouteComponentProps, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import './App.css'
import { Error } from './Error/Error'
import { Game } from './Game/Game'
import { Loading } from './Loading/Loading'

interface AppProps extends RouteComponentProps<any> { }

interface AppState {
  person: object[]
  loading: boolean | string
  error: null
}

export default  class App extends Component<AppProps, AppState> {
  public state = {
    error: null,
    loading: true,
    person: [],
  }
  public async componentDidMount() {
    const url = 'myApi'
    try {
      const res = await fetch(url)
      const data = await res.json()
      this.setState({ person: data, loading: false })
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error, loading: false })
      console.error(error)
    }
  }

  public gameRoute = (props: any, state: object) => {
    return <Game {...props} {...this.state} />
  }

  public render(): JSX.Element {
    const { person, loading, error } = this.state
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="App">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/play-game">Play Game!</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/play-game" render={this.gameRoute} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

**I'm flying in the dark here so your guidance would be much appreciated**

Here's my package.json just in case:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^23.3.12",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.7.18",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.11",
    "@types/react-router": "^4.4.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "tslint-check": "tslint-config-prettier-check ./tslint.json",
    "lint": "tslint -c tslint.json src/**/*.{ts,tsx} --fix --format verbose"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "tslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.0.1",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0"
  }
}
```